# Bootstrap 3 nav-pills, active class works only after I click assigned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following code for `nav-pills` component:

```
  <ul id="steps" class="nav nav-pills form-steps">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#options"></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#payments"></a></li>
  </ul>
```

And this is my `tab-content` just to make sure that `href` and `id` are equal:

```
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="options">
      <%= render 'options' %>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="payments">
      <%= render 'payments' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is how the look of active `a` is made (basically it's just a circle filled with special color):

```
.form-steps > li.active > a {
    background-color: #931f2a;
}
```

And here's code for a regular `a`:

```
.form-steps > li > a {
    border: 2px solid #931f2at;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

I suppose that by adding `.active` class to corresponding `li` element makes `a` element filled with color, but it doesn't when I open modal where this component is placed for the fist time, to activate this color I must click on the link, right after that my element is filled. When I open modal for the second time after I click on another link, I see correct behavior, i.e `.active` class is filled with color. It's an SPA and I have another `nav-pills` like this with exact markup and it works just fine and I don't quite understand why this behavior doesn't work on second `nav-pills`. I double checked that class names and ids don't repeat each others and I am sure that no custom js was involved into this.
Can you please give me a direction to inspect what I did wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A jsfiddle or similar would be helpful

Comment: Have you checked on developer tools to identify the css being applied when modal is opened?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these css:

`.form-steps > li.active > a:focus {
    background-color: #931f2a;
}`

`.form-steps > li.active > a:active {
    background-color: #931f2a;
}`

`.form-steps > li.active > a:visited {
    background-color: #931f2a;
}`